# Missing email activity when SendEmail failed: EMAIL_ADDRESS_BOUNCED, The target object email address is currently marked as bounced

Tags: apex, email, singleemailmessage, bounce-management

Salesforce recently stopped creating email activity records for emails which failed because they bounce.

Below is the error I am getting:

> SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
>   EMAIL_ADDRESS_BOUNCED, The target object email address is currently
>   marked as bounced.: [targetObjectId, ...]

When I use the below code:

```
public static Messaging.SendEmailResult sendEmail(Id whatId, Id emailTemplateId, String emailTemplateDeveloperName, String orgWideEmailId, Id targetObjectId, String emailAddress, Boolean saveActivity) {

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

    if (String.isNotBlank(emailTemplateId)){

        mail.setTemplateId(emailTemplateId);

    } else if (String.isNotBlank(emailTemplateDeveloperName)){

        mail.setTemplateId(getEmailTemplateId(emailTemplateDeveloperName));    
    }

    if (String.isNotBlank(whatId)){
        mail.setWhatId(whatId);
    }

    if (String.isNotBlank(targetObjectId)){

        mail.setTargetObjectId(targetObjectId); 

    } else if (String.isNotBlank(emailAddress)) {

        mail.setToAddresses(new String[] {emailAddress}); 
    }

    if (String.isNotBlank(orgWideEmailId)){
        mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(orgWideEmailId); 
    }

    mail.setSaveAsActivity(saveActivity);
    mail.setOptOutPolicy('FILTER');

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    messages.add(mail);

    Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);

    handleEmailResults(results);

    return results[0];
}

private static void handleEmailResults(Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results) {

    for(Messaging.SendEmailResult result :results) {                

        if(!result.IsSuccess()) {                    
            List<Messaging.SendEmailError> errors = result.getErrors();
            if (errors.size() > 0){
                Messaging.SendEmailError err = errors[0];
                System.debug(err.getMessage());       
            }                   
        }
    } 
}
```

I've doubled checked, and `setSaveAsActivity` is definitely being set to `true`

**Question**

1. Why aren't the email activities being created?
2. What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why aren't the email activities being created?

Emails that fail to send are not saved as an activity. For example, if it is missing a subject, recipient, etc, it will not be saved anywhere.

> What can I do to fix it?

You need to check if it failed, and manually save activities if you want to record the activity.

Comment: OK, so it will send the first email, then once Salesforce gets the bounce back the contact is marked as *Bounced* and the email activity for the first email gets the little exclamation icon, but all subsequent emails fail to even send because the contact is marked as *Bounced* and Salesforce automatically rejects them?

Comment: @Robs Correct. [Bounce Mail Management](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_bounce_mail_management.htm&type=5) is designed to prevent you from sending emails to bounced emails. This is particularly useful for Mass Email, since you'd normally be "charged" against your 5,000 emails/day limit, but emails blocked this way don't count.

Comment: If I manually create an email activity record will it automatically be marked as *bounced* with the useful exclamation icon because the related contact is marked as *bounced*?

Comment: @Robs I think so? The docs aren't clear on this, and I don't have time to set it up and test it today.

Comment: Thanks. No need to build it for me, just wondering if you already knew :)